# html2canvas font has been changed after downloading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I'm working with a html file that will converted by canvas and prepare an image for download.

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row p-0">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 p-0"  id="html-content-holder">
             //html code is here
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://files.codepedia.info/files/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
        var getCanvas; // global variable
        $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
            html2canvas(element, {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    // $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                    getCanvas = canvas;
                   
                }
            });
            var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
            $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", <?php echo $order->customer->phone;?>+".png").attr("href", newData);
        });
        window.stop();
    </script>
```

All is ok, good convert, but problem is that font has been changed after downloading, specially when downloading from desktop.

Comment: do you use latin language text or non-latin language text, the html2canvas has some trouble rendering non-latin font like thai,chinese, arabic ,....

Comment: I'm using Latin language,  but still now font changes

Comment: You can try **dom-to-image** library. It supports both, Latin and Non Latin characters